# After Upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, Indicator Applets are not showing in LXDE

Tags: 14.04, lxde

after I updated to Ubuntu 14.04 and I use LXDE as my main DE. The indicator applet is not showing anymore even though I listed in the Add / Remove panel items. Anyone is also facing this problem? :)